# Display hint of any widget on mouse over in tcl tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is it possible to display the widget hint on mouseover of widget ?

Answer (score 2):

Every Tk widget is sent an `<Enter>` event when the mouse pointer goes over it, and is sent a `<Leave>` event when the mouse pointer goes elsewhere.

```
# Make some widgets; the buttons are much larger than the status text
pack [button .b1 -text "First button" -font {Arial 24}]
pack [button .b2 -text "Second button" -font {Arial 24}]
pack [label .l1 -textvariable status -font {Arial 10}]

# Set up some simple bindings
bind .b1 <Enter> {set status "Over the first button"}
bind .b1 <Leave> {set status ""}
bind .b2 <Enter> {set status "Over the second button"}
bind .b2 <Leave> {set status ""}
```

That's the core of how you do this sort of thing. The other major thing to note is that when you click on a widget, a temporary grab is set so that all (mouse-related) events get sent to that widget until the mouse button is released. If you're wanting to work out what widget the mouse is over and you've not got it directly from the event, the `winfo containing` command is exactly the right tool.

Comment: Is it possible to have balloon hint like html "abbr" tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tooltip` package which should be among the default packages of Tcl.

```
package require tooltip

pack [label .l -text "Hover your mouse over me!"]
tooltip::tooltip .l "I'm a helpful hint!"
```

Reference:

- [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10551)
- [manual](https://core.tcl.tk/tklib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tklib/files/modules/tooltip/tooltip.html)

Comment: It says "can't find package tooltip". Should i install it manually? I am using Tcl8.5

Comment: @Saran Try to find it in the Tcl folders. My Tcl couldn't find it too on my second machine (I don't remember what I did on my first to make it work) but right now I use `tcl::tm::path add {C:\Tcl\lib\teapot\package\tcl\teapot\tcl8\8.4}` before `package require` (I'm on Windows). If you cannot find the tooltip file somewhere, then you'll have to install it. The wiki has the necessary links